# Gmail APIs get messages

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I used this example https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/To-Read-Gmail-Inbox-fom-4132202a I tried to use Gmail APIs but returned the below error url That’s an error. Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

The redirect URI in the request, http://127.0.0.1:50528/authorize/, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. To update the authorized redirect URIs, visit:

I need to connect to Gmail APIs (get emails,send email.....) I using asp.net APIs project with angular 2,,, I added the my Credentials console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials after this I run the project but still dislay redirect url error –